# Python webapp Google app engine: no module named six

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

The following code should take 2 dates from `input.html` and display months and years in `output.html`, but the Google app engine returns an error saying module six is missing, even though I have added all the site packages in my project library.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import webapp2   
import jinja2   
import os   
import time   
import datetime  
import sys   
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libs")) 

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')  
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)  
def render_str(template, **params):  
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)  
    return t.render(params)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):  
    def write(self, *a, **kw):  
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

    def get(self):
        self.render('input.html')
    def post(self):
        frmstring=self.request.get('from')
        tostring=self.request.get('to')
        frm=time.strptime(frms,"%Y-%m")
        to=time.strptime(tos,"%Y-%m")
        dates = [dt for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=frm, until=to)]
        months_choices = []
        for i in range(1,13):
            months_choices.append(datetime.date(2008, i, 1).strftime('%B'))
        self.render('output.html',dates = dates,months_choices=months_choices)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: html code for output.html is:  

<ol>  
 {% for date in dates %}  
 <li>{{months_choices[date.month - 1], date.year}}</li>  
</ol>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to vendor six into your environment.

Run

```
pip install -t lib six
```

Then add these lines to your apppengine_config.py file (or create it)

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library for more details

Answer (score 1):

The `six` module is not provided by the AppEngine environment. Have you included it in your `lib/` directory?